# If permalink is equal to current site url

Tags: permalinks

Is there a way to add a class to a div, when the current site url is equal to the permalink of a post?

I need a class "current" to my custom made menu. I put the posts links in a list item with a loop, and for every link i want to check if the permalink is equal to the current page url. If the permalink matches the current page url, i want to add the class "current".

Something like:

```
<?php $currentUrl = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>
<?php if ( $currentUrl == the_permalink() ) { echo ' class="current"'; } else {} ?>
```

Together with the loop:

```
<?php $currentUrl = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>

<?php query_posts('orderby=name'); ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

   <li>
       <a <?php if ( $currentUrl == the_permalink() ) { echo ' class="current"'; } else {} ?>
       href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
          <?php the_title() ?>
       </a>
   </li>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would do something simplier using ID :

```
<?php $current_id = $post->ID; ?>
<?php query_posts('orderby=name'); ?>  
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

   <li>
       <?php $current_class = ( $current_id == $post->ID ) ? 'class="current"' : ''; ?>
       <a <?php if ( $current_class ) echo $current_class; ?> href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
          <?php the_title() ?>
       </a>
   </li>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

I didn't had time to verify code, hope this helps.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm doing a small editing for not echoing nothing.